# Joomla Zoo - user profile

Tags: php, joomla, profile

I have a question, help me please.

Can I create custom profiles for users in joomla 2.5+zoo? I need special profiles, with special settings/capabilities. Example:

Just register users see in profile there posts, reviews etc.

Representatives see in their profile edit options for there posts, new reviews for there posts, etc.

I think I must use joomla community builder.

**Update:**
Thank you for answering. But I don’t think ticket system can help me. I already have site build with zoo. In this site all members and guests can publish posts. Now I need to do profile system for all members (like mini administration panel for users in profiles). In profile user can see list of his posts, PM, etc. Available functions in profile changing  for each user group (member, administrator, author, etc). Need full integration in zoo.

If I not right or described something wrong – please correct me :)

P.S: Maybe somebody know statistic module (want show it in sidebar) what can show zoo items with top rating, new reviews, etc (joomla+zoo+jcomments). Maybe I can use zoo item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure zoo is your best choice here: as of last year it was lacking most access control configuration, which I had to manually add (at the risk of it breaking with a new release).

But from your description you seem to need a ticketing system / Q&A, may I suggest https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/ats.html Akeeba Ticket System, its solid, extensive functionality includes complete integration with Joomla Groups and an extensive guide on setting them up.

Community Builder doesn't include a Q&A so you would be adding a huge component and still need to resort to hacks and code changes to integrate it with zoo.

---- edit ----
Ok so you're back to adding ACLs support to Zoo. Still no CB is necessary. You might want to try aclmanager.

Also see here http://www.yootheme.com/support/question/11472 for a more complete reference (and rants about the missing ACL features, and a direct tip to achieve it without the aclmanager: http://www.aclmanager.net/blog/general/31-how-to-add-basic-acl-support-to-your-extension)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think ticketing system can help in this situation :(